# Get all combinations from selenium drop down list without options or select tag

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I am working with Selenium for the corresponding website:http://calstate-la.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBWizardView?catalogId=10001&langId=-1&storeId=30556.

My goal with this website is to get all the possible combinations of departments, course, and section from their respective drop down menus. The main problem I am having is that I can't think of any way to get the values from the drop down menus.

According to other stack overflow problems similar to mine, they mention solutions working with select tags and option tags. However, when I was looking at this page source there were no such tags for the drop down menu.

So I need help in trying to get all the combinations from the drop down menu but I don't how to proceed in my special case. Also I wanted to mention that I working with Python.

Comment: These are not drop-down menus, they are AJAX calls to make the data **look like** a drop-down. If you inspect the webpage, you will notice all the information that you are looking for is in lists, `<li>` elements.

Comment: So how would I be able to click on each of the list elements? Would I simply search for the `<li>` tags and do a click?

Comment: What happened when you tried that? From your original post, it is not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish. If "My goal with this website is to get all the possible combinations ...", then Selenium is overkill! You could just grab the website HTML (with something like `wget`), and just parse out the information you want.

Comment: Well to be exact, I need to input all the combinations into the the departments, courses, and sections and from there I need to click on find materials. Once I get the resulting html page, I am going to save it and parse it using BeautifulSoup. My ultimate goal is to get all the books from the website.

Comment: If you are just datamining a site, then Selenium is definitely overkill - takes too long, and it's too brittle. Also, keep in mind the owner of the site (assuming you did **not** get permission) might get pissed off! But I digress. Try something, and come back when you have something to show us. With a 300+ rep, you must have already read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually tried to use `selenium` here, but it really becomes painful very fast due to async nature of the page and "artificial" dropdowns ([here is what I had so far](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/b8cad2bd779a92c23a95)).

Here's an alternative approach using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (no need for browser at all).

The idea is to simulate the udnerlying requests that fill up the dropdowns:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

CATALOG = 10001
STORE = 30556

url = 'http://calstate-la.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBWizardView?catalogId={catalog}&langId=-1&storeId={store}'.format(catalog=CATALOG,
                                                                                                                                     store=STORE)
xhr_url = 'http://calstate-la.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TextBookProcessDropdownsCmd'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

campus = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'campus1'}).get('value')
book_row = soup.find('div', class_='bookRowContainer')

params = {
    'campusId': campus,
    'deptId': '',
    'courseId': '',
    'sectionId': '',
    'storeId': STORE,
    'catalogId': CATALOG,
    'langId': '-1',
    'dropdown': 'term'
}

terms = book_row.select('li.termOption')
for term in terms:
    params['termId'] = term.get('data-optionvalue')
    response = session.post(xhr_url, params=params, headers=headers)
    print response.content
```

This would print all of the departments for all terms in JSON format.

For Fall 2014:

```
[
    {"categoryName":"AAAS","categoryId":"63420700","categoryIdentifier":"670_1_F14_4","title":"AAAS"},
    {"categoryName":"ACCT","categoryId":"63420752","categoryIdentifier":"670_1_F14_5","title":"ACCT"},
    ...
]
```

For Summer 2014:

```
[
    {"categoryName":"AAAS","categoryId":"63007512","categoryIdentifier":"670_1_A14_4","title":"AAAS"},
    {"categoryName":"ACCT","categoryId":"63007490","categoryIdentifier":"670_1_A14_5","title":"ACCT"},
    ...
]
```

Leaving you `Course` and `Section` part as a homework.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey @alexce, the reason why I wanted to use selenium is similar to my other post in which I need to get all the combinations and then click on find materials to find all the books for a given class. Is this feature of selenium supported in beautiful soup and requests?

Comment: @user2548635 you can actually continue using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` and simulate requests going for book searches too. It is definitely doable. I've also posted a link to the code I had for selenium-approach - you can try to adjust it too.

Comment: I will definitely check it out and work on it. Thanks for the help and I will ask back if there are any questions.

Comment: @user2548635 sure, this is an interesting task. I like this kind of challenges :)